# What would be US Military procedure for investigating a portal to another world?

Tags: science-fiction, military-defense, urban-fantasy

Here's the scenario I'm working with: a portal opens up within 30 minutes' drive of one of the better equipped military installations in the continental United States. It is stable, shows no signs of growing or shrinking, and no one comes through from the other side. On investigation, the other side contains a medieval environment with some "unusual" changes.

Given existing data about discovering a potential hostile infiltration, and surveying unknown territory, how might the real military handle something like that? Which branch would be tapped first to head up the investigation?

I am aware Stargate is a franchise that exists, but it is not ideally suited to answer my question. I am also aware it is unlikely the military has a "magic portal protocol." I'm asking for speculation from as much real data as possible.

Comment: Weren't there a successful [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_(film)) and [several very popular television series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate#Television) documenting in detail how this was done?

Comment: I am not willing to trust a fictional source with very specific parameters, when there may be informed individuals on this site who have some more helpful insight. I'm looking to hear things like whether the Air Force would actually be the go-to, ideally. How aggressive would the approach be? That kind of thing. Stargate had a very specific story to tell, with an ancient mechanical portal device. My question is only assuming that the portal exists, not that there's a machine responsible on either end.

Comment: Isn't how a fictional government would respond to a fictional portal up to the author? It basically _is_ a story, after all. Assuming a response has already been planned in the real world, and that this response is publically available seems a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Please, this is the worldbuilding Stack Exchange. All I'm asking for is a morsel of creativity, based on any hearsay, data, or personal experience based on standard procedure in slightly more normal environments.

But sure, I'll help a little more. I'll edit the question to have a more specific leaning.

Comment: I don't get it. You *already have* your "morsel of creativity". The script writers for *Stargate* did it for you. No, no self-respecting military of this world has ever published what they would intend to do in the event that a fairy tale magical gate opens near one of their bases, leading to a world-just-like-Earth but only-so-slightly-different orbiting a distant star. (Mostly because such an event is extremely improbable. Why would the general staff of any armed forces waste time developing a contingency plan for something which is almost guaranteed to never happen?)

Comment: I didn't come here to be told "just watch the show you already invested 13 seasons of show-watching in." I wouldn't just assume that Men In Black would be the way handling aliens would go. I wouldn't just assume Stargate is anywhere near accurate to real operating procedure.

What kind of person signs on to a forum like this with so little interest in asking "what if?"

Comment: P.S. The Air Force would be most likely the *last* branch of service to be tasked with the exploration. Whatever is on the other side of the gate, it is guaranteed to *not have* American air bases. Aircraft are kind of helpless without the love and care they get on air base. Rangers, marines, such types who are trained to operate on their own in hostile territory, much more likely. Ah, and by the way, you may want to revisit the [help] and the [tour]; it may be the case that you are confusing this web site with a discussion forum.

Comment: That is much more what I was looking for. Stargate put this in the hands of the Air Force, for reasons I didn't quite follow. The assumption I operated on was that they simply had possession of it when the scientists got it working. They are not who I'd assume would get picked.

Comment: Missing information required for answers - who discovered the portal, how did they discover it and who knows about it?  Also, how addicted are you to having the US military being the "exploring" force?  Especially given that it is on US soil, they probably are not first choice

Comment: I didn't have a discoverer in mind, though the nearby base would doubtless know about it within 15 minutes tops of whatever civilian found it. I'm picturing it to be out in the open, rather than in someone's house or within their fence. Maybe in the middle of a neglected country road?

As for my "addiction" to the US military exploring it, I have none. It was my assumption they would be concerned, especially if there was a chance of hostiles coming through.

Are you thinking US government? They would never let a foreign power near it. That much I'm sure of.

Comment: You seem to be assuming there is some sort of existing protocol for this scenario in the real world. If you want a real world analogy, research protocols for first contact with alien life. There's very little existing published information on this, presumably because the military doesn't take it particularly seriously. I think it's likely this is an unanswerable question since you're asking how the real world military would react to a situation that has never occurred before and it's extremely unlikely they have planned for.

Comment: I am making no such assumption, but there are protocols in place for many scenarios far more likely than this, some of which could likely give precedent for creating one. That, and guesswork as to who would step through first, are the objectives I'm aiming at.

Comment: @PastAndFuture Hi and welcome! First, this problem might fit in here except please look closely at what you want from this site, because we *specifically do not* engage in brainstorming or speculation: “I'm asking for speculation from…” All *we* want is for the question to [be presented consistant with our rules](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) so when the public sees your post, they know what to expect: Objective expert solutions to actual problems in your imagined world. It is true, there are *no* scenarios that leave the US military guessing; just focus please.

Comment: And if you need to edit a few times to get it right, no problem. It can be re-opened and stay live on the site when it fits our standards.

Comment: In the USA, the State would have initial jurisdiction. Initial coordination of a response would be by the State's Emergency Operations Center. The State governor might activate National Guard troops to, for example, operate the cordon. Local universities would send the first investigators and discover the differences. The laws of the USA prohibit Federal troops for domestic use without several rather public steps to be satisfied; secrecy would be almost impossible. Since there is no law dealing with such magic, Congress must make a few laws outlining the long-term status of portals.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**First contact**

This is a potential first contact situation.  While the US government probably does not have a playbook ready for "fantasy portal opens up in nearby woodland", I'm willing to bet that they do have a playbook ready for "aliens land on Earth and we want to make friends with them before anyone else (so we get their technology first)".  So they will dust off that piece of contingency planning and modify it to suit the situation.

Step 1a.  Quarantine and contain the area.  Given the restrictions on the US Army and Air Force operating on US soil due to the [Posse Comitatus Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posse_Comitatus_Act), I would expect this to be conducted by a mix of local / state police / FBI with wildlife control agencies added in on the fly.  Homeland Security will probably have primacy given that this is a national threat which requires coordinating the efforts of many different agencies.  The huge threat here, much greater than with visitors from outer space, is that there are bacterial or viral agents that will come across the gate that Earth lifeforms have no resistance to and, contrariwise, that our bugs may cross over and kill any native life on the other side.

As part of this, establish this as controlled airspace and keep everyone out.  This will almost certainly require National Guard action to knock down any drones that intrusive civilians (or foreign spooks pretending to be such) send into the area in addition to dealing with manned aircraft.

Step 1b.  Gather up any people who did wander across the portal or spent time in its vicinity and put them in quarantine pending step 2a.  In the meantime, debrief them extremely thoroughly on everything they observed.

Step 2a.  Bring in people from the Centre for Disease Control to assess the microbiological threat - use sterilised drones and people in sterile suits with rebreathers to check everything possible on this side of the portal and maybe push sampling devices onto the other side of the portal.

Step 2b.  Bring in the first contact team as per the contingency planning that is established and get them ready to go.  I have no idea which agency would have the lead on this, but they would doubtless end up under Homeland Security's control.
Modify the first-contact-with-aliens linguistics plan to add more current/ancient Earth language linguists ready to consult - if there's a portal now then there may have been one in the past with linguistic cross-contamination.  It's a very different task working out a language with a star-faring alien who is going to be familiar with universal physical constants to a medieval tech-level native, so the approach for establishing communications will change.

If a sapient native stumbles across the portal then attempt peaceful contact.  If non-sapient large wildlife stumbles across the portal then attempt to capture and analyse.

Step 2c.  Get physicists in to try to figure out what the portal is, how it works, how stable it is etc, with all tests conducted using sterilised equipment and, as much as possible, from "our" side only.  If essential then use EOD robots or drones to place sensors on the other side, but do not send people across.  As part of this work, conduct tests to determine how communications across the portal boundary work - light, radio, cable, sound.

Step 3.  Using a method dependent on the outcome of step 3 testing to establish a base station a few metres on the other side of the portal, send small, sterilised, unarmed UAVs to survey and map the area - initially out to a few hundred metres, then a few kilometres etc, taking all possible precautions to avoid being observed by natives.  UAVs will be rigged to destroy vital components without collateral damage (probably using acid) if in danger of capture.

What happens after this would be dependent on the outcome of the tests and surveys conducted above and the decisions made at the political level.  The key thing is that no responsibly conducted investigation would send people across an inexplicable portal until the maximum possible amount of information had been conducted using sterilised drones and remote sensors.

I realise that I'm harping on about the microbiological threat, but the reality is that something as simple as a disease that *bees* on the other side of the gate had no immunity to has more potential to destroy one or both civilisations than a full-on armed conflict.  So while Homeland Security would take point on management, expect CDC and the US Department of Agriculture to have high-level seats at the table.

Comment: This is so much of what I was looking for, in so many important ways. Citing the Posse Comitatus Act, indicating the levels of security and stages of cautious analysis that would be likely to occur, so much good here.

The microbiology is not to be underestimated. I very much appreciate all the focus on it by you and others. There's no real way to know how any modern power would handle a discovery like "magic," but there are numerous mundane areas of observation.

Comment: One point.  No military commander would ever send anything, not even a scouting drone, into foreign territory without political backup.

Comment: You seem to have completely overlooked the problem of stopping anyone coming out.  The National Guard are going to be there with heavy weapons, and all those weapons are going to be pointing towards the gate.  Stopping random civilians flying drones is cute, but stopping a massed cavalry charge is the priority.  The main reason for maintaining air control isn't stopping random drones going in there, it's stopping random drones running into your AH64s and A10s.

Answer (score 3):

### Part of medieval Flanders on Earth.. but

When it was first discovered, the army immediately decided to consider the place a state secret.

Checkpoints were established around the gate, preventing any civilians to enter the area and see the gate. Then, they sent a reconaissance unit in, which resulted in your *"On investigation, the other side contains a medieval environment with some unusual changes."*

At first, this was considered a relief. No dangerous aliens are emerging from the gate, *and* the world behind it seems to be low-tech. But the advice of several army doctors resulted in a 2-week quarantaine for the expedition, the army then covered  their find more thoroughly.. a plastic container was used to seal off this gate air-tight, to prevent any germs or viruses to escape from the gate and spread on Earth.

The army guarded the place for several months, nothing happened.

Science kicked in: the first scientist invited to join a military expedition into the gate was [Jonathan Lyon of the University of Chicago](https://network.expertisefinder.com/experts/jonathan-lyon-1), a known expert on medieval Europe.

Lyon determined the medieval architecture matched 13th century Flanders, which was again considered a relief by the military: there had never been a Belgian citizen in American history, who behaved hostile toward the United States. The unusual changes were kept a state secret, other details and Lyon's findings were declassified.. The first journalists started to appear.

The next expert who was consulted had all cameras point at her: [Sabine Hossenfelder](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=sabine+hossenfelder), a well known expert on  theoretical physics. She postulated the gate has to be a space-time anomaly local to Earth, somehow providing a gate to another era on Earth. The "unusual changes" were explained by Hossenfelder too, stating the world behind the gate exists in a separate time line from ours. Again good news: it would be safe to enter, there would be no issue with paradoxes. Everyone became optimistic. The gate could be turned into a tourist attraction, becoming more popular than Disneyland.

**Nuke it**

But then.. it happened. Some of these "unusual changes" started to pop up, in the vicinity of the gate. The army became very nervous and a general proposed to nuke the place. The president agreed: when unusual phenomena start spreading around, taking any risk must be avoided.

Hossenfelder was consulted again, and she assured the president there was no danger of causing paradoxes.

A B83 variable-yield thermonuclear gravity bomb was dropped on the gate, destroying its vicinity. After the blast, they found the gate intact. No effect.. but a large region of the medieval world on the other side was changed into a nuclear waste land, like its surroundings on Earth.

And the "unusual changes" reappeared too.. on either side of the gate.. They had solved nothing.

Comment: Would a nuke really be dropped within a stone's throw of a major military base and assorted residences? I suppose evacuations would be possible, but that's less practical with the base that close.

Aside from that, I love your take on this. Barring any significant anomalies on the other side that would protect them against a weapon of such magnitude, which should be fairly unlikely, this series of outcomes seems probable.

Comment: Yes @PastAndFuture .. A hydrogen bomb will be dropped, if *anything* would emerge from this gate. Your "unusual changes" would be considered a planet-wide security risk, whatever it is. Of course, there was a warning beforehand, the population was evacuated in a few hours. The base and a lot of weaponry and ammunition got destroyed, though.. and it didn't help.

Comment: What kind of restrictions would be encountered, if any, to prevent such a bomb from being used on US soil?

Comment: Probably several.. the US did sign [international agreements](https://www.jfklibrary.org/learn/about-jfk/jfk-in-history/nuclear-test-ban-treaty) on nuclear tests on land, and they risk international protests doing this. But again.. if these "unusual changes" would be uncontrollable, it might be a plausible decision to attempt destroy the gate. Could you disclose a little about these "unusual changes" ? (or would that be copyrighted :d )

Comment: The original post (before edit) said "unusual sciences" referring to magic. I'm assuming the government's brightest minds wouldn't look at a wizard throwing a fireball and feel comfortable with the conclusion "Oh so it's magic." Probably regard it as some unknown science.

Comment: Correct @PastAndFuture ! that MUST have been a typo, thanks.. I made another edit, changing the title and separating the second part. Reading over your first comment, maybe that is better ;)

Comment: Interesting, this reads a lot like an Eric Flint novel!

Answer (score 2):

### More than the military will be interested in this portal.

Scientists the world over will want to document and test how this occurred.
First and foremost, most parties will agree to begin with containment.

If there is any chance hostiles could invade, military wants to have a door they could control. Threats can come in many forms:

- Armed attackers waging an invasion.
- Invasive species of insects, plants, or fungus getting loose.
- Illnesses both airborne or carried over via a host.

Researchers would want a controlled environment for testing and researching:

- Protect the portal from external forces destroying it.
- Record readings from the portal with a little background noise as possible.

Once contained, then an probing exercise could begin, but for all they know during this discovery period, there's nothing keeping the portal from changing it's exit location to where lava begins spewing out of the thing or any other possibilities.

Comment: And don't forget the small nasties, viruses, bacteria, the like. If the world on the other side is indeed just-like-Earth but only-so-slightly-different it may very well have a large stock of pathogens sufficiently similar to ours to be dangerous, yet different enough that our immune systems are totally unprepared for them. Containment indeed.

Comment: That's what I'd expect, they'd probably want to be beyond certain it was not an active threat before they sent so much as a thrown pebble through. Would the Army be in charge of containment? CDC? Somebody else?

Comment: If this were to occur IRL, the whole world would want to know about it, get their hands on it, or stay as far away from it as possible. If this is the only portal that exists, it may spark a war if it's seen to have enough value to fight over. At first though, who ever found it would be wise to keep it under wraps to prevent this. So not only do we need to contain the thing, who do we tell and when?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider your program as analogous to space explorations.  Different countries have done this different ways.

**NASA will be in charge in the US.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Astronaut_Corps

> The first U.S. astronaut candidates were selected by NASA in 1959, for
> its Project Mercury with the objective of orbiting astronauts around
> the Earth in single-man capsules. The military services were asked to
> provide a list of military test pilots who met specific
> qualifications. After stringent screening, NASA announced its
> selection of the "Mercury Seven" as its first astronauts. Since then,
> NASA has selected 20 more groups of astronauts, opening the corps to
> civilians, scientists, doctors, engineers, and school teachers. As of
> the 2009 Astronaut Class 61% of the astronauts selected by NASA have
> come from military service

It looks like India's manned space program runs along [similar lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Department_of_Space).

**A more interesting fiction might be Soviet style with competing government sponsored factions**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_space_program

> Unlike the American space program, which had NASA as a single
> coordinating structure directed by its administrator, James Webb
> through most of the 1960s, the USSR's program was split between
> several competing design groups.

As far as I can tell the Chinese have a different way: **a state owned corporation that oversees space exploration** as well as doing a variety of other things.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Aerospace_Science_and_Technology_Corporation

> The China Aerospace Science and Technology Corporation, or CASC, is
> the main contractor for the Chinese space program. It is state-owned
> and has a number of subordinate entities which design, develop and
> manufacture a range of spacecraft, launch vehicles, strategic and
> tactical missile systems, and ground equipment. It was officially
> established in July 1999 as part of a Chinese government reform drive,
> having previously been one part of the former China Aerospace
> Corporation. Various incarnations of the program date back to 1956.
>
> Along with space and defence manufacture, CASC also produces a number
> of civilian products such as machinery, chemicals, communications
> equipment, transportation equipment, computers, medical care products
> and environmental protection equipment...

I propose that in your story, the portal opens in the nation of Brunei.  The government there is interested in doing some exploring itself but recognizes that other nations are interested in fielding exploration teams.  In the interest of fairness and equal treatment, several different countries are invited to oversee explorations through the Brunei portal.

Comment: I question if it taking place in Brunei would make it more likely that someone would nuke the site, or less. I honestly can't totally rule out Goodies' notion of the US nuking their own territory, but would they really nuke Brunei?

Aside from that, I like your idea. My primary focus was on answering who would be first through, in an official capacity, but this is a good alternative.

Comment: Brunei was not supposed to be a nuke deterrent - that is in Goodies fevered brain, not the OP.  I picked Brunei because I could imagine them inviting a variety of countries to participate which seems like fun fiction to me.  In addition to the gate and its weird world, you have these different factions bouncing off each other in various ways.

Answer (score 1):

1. Lots of frantic calls quickly go up to the highest levels. The president, key members of congress, and powerful military officials quickly learn of the portal. A bunch of armoured trucks and tanks and military vehicles are sent to it to secure it.
2. The Pentagon has plans [to fight off alien invasions](https://www.military.com/video/logistics-and-supplies/military-equipment/us-military-preparing-for-alien-invasion/1564996010001). They dust off one of their secret plans and get to work. Experts are recruited, sworn to secrecy, and moved to the site. Experts in drones, computing, invasion, linguistics, and lots of things are moved in. There's a big build up around the site, with lots of heavier weapons moved in. Who controls it depends on who is most influential and close. Everyone wants a piece of the action.
3. They start to spy and explore. Spy drones are moved in to look around. Bugs are planted in any residential areas to start learning the language. Efforts are made to move rockets to the location so they can start setting up spy satellites. Elon Musk tweets a cryptic tweet about events.
4. At some point, information gets out because there's a lot of people involved. The NSA and FBI try to keep it secret as best they can and suppress news of it while they study.
5. Once the local culture is understood, the USA sends in an active negotiation team, which could range from people to talk to nuclear warheads, depending on the threat.

Comment: Given that the portal is not on military property, would there be any laws in place to limit federal involvement in what could be termed a state issue? That has the potential to blow up politically.

Comment: War and diplomacy is under federal laws, and the federal government has a lot of authority to do whatever is needed when there is a prospect of war with a foreign nation.

Answer (score -3):

Given that the question specifically states it happens in the US I have to question federal involvement, particularly if the thing opens on privately owned land. In that latter case I could easily see the land owner saying "stay the fuck out" and the government not getting enough confirmation until whatever risks have settled out. I.E. if the bio-hazard scenarios are actually the case then everyone's dead, if there's no risk then that too is known, and in that case there would be even less immediate cause to do anything.

I do, however, expect that somewhere in a Pentagon file this situation (or something close enough) has actually been considered, if for no other reason than that it makes people give more serious thought to things that could really happen.

Comment: While I'm not in the US myself, I believe it is safe to assume that in the event of "Magical portal which uproots everything we think to know about the universe and which could be an existential threat to our entire species", whichever individual has this spawn in their backyard will have their property rights thoroughly violated, should they seriously try to argue that the feds should "stay the fuck out"

Comment: You cannot tell the US government to stay off your land if they have a legitimate reason to be on your land.  I can think of many scenarios under far more normal circumstances where they can not only intrude on your land, but also order you to leave or evacuate.